# uwsgi flask application got nginx variables unexpanded

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Strange problem with nginx variables passed after redirect to python code through uwsgi_pass -> uwsgi -> flask. uWSGI itself sees variables like $uri or $request_filename expanded. My python code sees them just as "$uri" and "$request_filename"

nginx config:

```
location /l0 {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:4001;
}

location /spool {
    set $file_path $request_filename;
    post_action /l2;
}

location /l2 {
           internal;
           include uwsgi_params;
           uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI /foo/bar=$file_path;
           uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:4001;
           limit_except GET {
                allow all;
           }
 }
```

uwsgi app started with:

```
/usr/bin/uwsgi_python --socket :4001 --python-path /my/path --module my.module --callable      app --need-app
```

I see from the log that uwsgi got the request with $uri expanded (i.e. "/some/path"). In my code I see just "$uri" (see log line `my_2nd_handler got mypath=/foo/bar=$uri`)

Code:

```
app = Flask('myapp')
@app.route('/l0', methods=['GET']):
def my_root_handler():
    r = Response()
    r.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/spool/file1'
    print "my_root_handler sent nginx to /spool/file1"
    return r

@app.route('/<path:mypath>', methods=['GET']):
def my_2nd_handler(mypath):
    print "my_2nd_handler got mypath="+mypath
```

Request:

```
 curl -X GET http://mysite/l0
```

Log:

```
my_root_handler sent nginx to /spool/file1
my_2nd_handler got mypath=/foo/bar=$uri
[pid: 21715|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.16.183.15 () {40 vars in 915 bytes} [Tue Jan 22 21:04:59 2013] GET /foo/bar=/spool/file1 => generated 116 bytes in 3 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 4 headers in 203 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

$request_filename isn't the only problem variable. I've tried several others with the same result.
How can I get nginx vars expanded in the python code?

Comment: change param like this, uwsgi_param key $request_uri; work?

Comment: Do you mean no dollar sigil in the uwsgi_param keys? If so it's already like this `uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI /foo/bar=$file_path;`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't find the source of the problem. For me it looks like a bug inside HttpUwsgiModule. I don't have time to dig. So I used workaround: I run another instance of the app by `uwsgi --http-socket` and use `proxy_pass` instead of `uwsgi_pass`. Works as a charm.